# Using Linq, get all items from list that are in another List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following scenario:
a list of int: `List<int> idsOnly = new List<int>();`
and another list of object that should bring all items that their ids matching the list idsOnly

```
var myList = db.Items.Where(item => idsOnly.Contains(item.ID.Value))
                     .Select(a => new { a.Title })
                     .ToList();
```

I only need to get the titles from the myList

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code works but it will create the list of anonymous object, not string type

Instead of using `(a => new { a.Title }`, you just use `a => a.Title` if you just only want to get the title:

```
var myList = db.Items.Where(item => idsOnly.Contains(item.ID.Value))
                     .Select(a => a.Title).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Join`

```
var titlesInIdList = from item in db.Items
                     join id in idsOnly
                     on item.ID.Value equals id
                     select item.Title;
var list = titlesInIdList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList =
    (from item in db.Items
    where idsOnly.Contains(item.ID.Value)
    select item.Title).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with (If problem conversion : Convert to int your Id, if is not of int type)

```
var myList = db.Items.Where(item => (idsOnly.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(item.ID.Value)))).Select(a => a.Title ).ToList();
```

Without conversion

```
var myList = db.Items.Where(item => (idsOnly.Contains(item.ID.Value))).Select(a => a.Title ).ToList();
```

Comment: If I want to maintain order of original list in my resulting list then what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Result = (from item in db.Items
                 join id in idsOnly
                 on item.ID.Value equals id
                 select new {item.Title}).ToList(); //Here U can return ToArray or ToList()
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.